# How can I find what makes a program crash on Windows?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am porting a SFML project I did on Linux to Windows.

When I launch my program, it exits right away with this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x73E4C9F5 in name: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
```

Problem is, my program works fine on the PC of other users...

It crashes on the creation of my window.

Have any idea how can I find why my program crash on my PC ? 
Is there any sort of gdb in Windows ?

This is my call stack :

```
>   00000000()  Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]  
    atiglpxx.dll!731238e7() Unknown
    atiglpxx.dll!73123770() Unknown
    [External Code] 
    atiglpxx.dll!73124597() Unknown
    [External Code] 
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c7cb5d()  Unknown
    [External Code] 
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c7b60d()  Unknown
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c7ae61()  Unknown
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c78f2a()  Unknown
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00cd33e3()  Unknown
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c78048()  Unknown
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c76e50()  Unknown
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c644ee()  Unknown
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c5b9f0()  Unknown
    [External Code] 
    The-Duck-Reborn.exe!00c86745()  Unknown
    [External Code]
```

EDIT: All SFML program I try to launch crashes... Maybe a lib is missing but how to find which ?

Comment: Yes there is a variety of debuggers that work on windows. Why not consult your toolchain?

Comment: Visual Studio has one the the best debuggers for C++

Comment: [gdb for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) (including gcc as well)

Comment: @bolov No it doesn't. Anyway, it might have something to do with your version of Windows.

Comment: @Poriferous:  There are lots of things wrong with VS - the debugger isn't one of them.

Comment: @Poriferous what do you mean `No it doesn't`? How is the VS debugger not good?

Comment: @bolov, VS in general _is not good_. When I were to build my [project](https://brute.tk) for Windows, _nothing_ was working, VS was refusing to find standard headers, etc, so I switched to MinGW-w64 and everything's working very nice since then

Comment: @ForceBru That's a case of PEBKAC, VS works excellently for me and millions of others.

Comment: I think this is the ultimate question, which one knew exactly how to answer, this world would have been a better place.

Answer (score 1):

Run it under the debugger, and see what it is doing when the Access Violation happens.

Then do it again to see why the variable is still a null pointer.

Comment: The address in question is 0x00000000

Answer (score 1):

Install visual studio, compile a debug build, configure debug symbols (TLDR: Tools, Options, Debugging, Symbols, check “Microsoft Symbol Server”), start with debugger, and you’ll see what happens.
Be sure to read the debug output (View, Output): often debug builds just print the reason why things fail.

The “gdb in Windows” is called windbg, and major parts of that is built into the OS.
[Here’s the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx).

It’s however *much* harder to use then visual studio’s debugger. But if you don’t have visual studio on the machine where it crashes, or can’t reliably reproduce the crash i.e. only have the dump, then you have to use that.